# apt-mark Holding a package to a major version (not a specific minor)

Tags: apt, dpkg

I want to hold versions of packages on my servers to prevent breaking changes in infrastructure from breaking our code (Changes from mongodb 2.4 to 2.6 for example..)

I know I can (for example) `apt-mark hold package` for example, but then I stop getting security patches and minor upgrades.

Also I would like to install packages with setting a major version (but not a minor)

for example I know I can:

```
sudo apt-get install -y rabbitmq-server=3.3.5
```

But I want to just pin installation to a major version (3.*)

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 5):

You can pin to a wildcard set of version numbers. See [`man apt_preferences`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/apt_preferences.5) for an example:

> The specific form assigns a priority (a "Pin-Priority") to one or more
>   specified packages with a specified version or version range. For
>   example, the following record assigns a high priority to all versions
>   of the perl package whose version number begins with "5.10". Multiple
>   packages can be separated by spaces.
>
> ```
> Package: perl
> Pin: version 5.10*
> Pin-Priority: 1001
> ```

So, for example, on Ubuntu 16.04, where `xenial-backports` has a default priority of 100, the initial policy for `debhelper` is:

```
$ apt-cache policy debhelper
debhelper:
  Installed: 9.20160115ubuntu3
  Candidate: 9.20160115ubuntu3
  Version table:
     10.2.2ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04.1 100
        100 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages
        100 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main i386 Packages
 *** 9.20160115ubuntu3 500
        500 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Then, I pinned backports to a higher priority:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/preferences.d/debhelper
Package: *
Pin: release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-backports,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
Pin-Priority: 600

$ apt-cache policy debhelper
debhelper:
  Installed: 9.20160115ubuntu3
  Candidate: 10.2.2ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04.1
  Version table:
     10.2.2ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04.1 600
        600 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages
        100 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main i386 Packages
 *** 9.20160115ubuntu3 500
        500 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
```

Again pinning `9.*` versions of `debhelper` to an even higher priority:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/preferences.d/debhelper
Package: *
Pin: release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-backports,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
Pin-Priority: 600

Package: debhelper
Pin: version 9.*
Pin-Priority: 800

$ apt-cache policy debhelper
debhelper:
  Installed: 9.20160115ubuntu3
  Candidate: 9.20160115ubuntu3
  Version table:
     10.2.2ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04.1 600
        600 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages
        100 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main i386 Packages
 *** 9.20160115ubuntu3 800
        500 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

So you just need to create a file in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/` that has:

```
Package: rabbitmq-server
Pin: version 3.*
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

No repository has a priority greater than 1000 by default, 1001 is enough to force apt to downgrade if needed:

> P >= 1000 causes a version to be installed even if this constitutes a
>   downgrade of the package.

Comment: But isn't there a way to do it as an argument to `sudo apt-get install`?

Comment: @cowlinator You can do something like `apt-get install 'rabbitmq-server=3.*'`, but then you won't be holding it, though (i.e., in the next upgrade it might well get updated to 4.x).

Comment: 1000 is enough to force apt to downgrade if needed. Note the `>=`.